# Is there any planet or black hole where we could experience time dilation like in the movie Interstellar?

Tags: black-hole, time-dilation, interstellar, multiple-star-systems

As we seen in Interstellar movie Copper goes to a planet where he experienced time dilation which was 1 hour of staying on that planet will cost the 7 years on the earth. So, is there any planet or black hole where time will nearly behave like this? Because the planets in our solar system will show very little differences.

Comment: Kip Thorne, a leading expert in gravitation & black holes (he literally is a co-author of the classic textbook *Gravitation*) was a science advisor for *Interstellar*, but they "modified" some of his advice for storytelling purposes.

Comment: We have several questions on that movie, both here & on the Physics site. You should do a search... ;) Note that the BH in the movie has a *very* high spin, which allows the planet to orbit very close to it

Comment: The classic short story "Neutron Star" comes to mind here. -Niven

Comment: @PM2Ring I saw somebody literally carrying around a >1000 page hardcover edition once; my brain froze trying to decide which of all the possible funny comments I should make.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Excellent reference! [How to get sunburned through the window of a General Products hull?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128375/51174)

Comment: @WayfaringStranger In *Neutron Star*, the important factor is the extreme tidal force. In *Interstellar*, Gargantua is a SMBH, so while the tidal force on Miller's planet is large it doesn't spaghettify everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely scratch out any *planets*, as their gravitational field will not be strong enough. Even a very dense neutron star wouldn’t give much effect, as far as I know.

As for black holes, well, basically *any* black hole will give this effect. However, those are too far to reach with our current means.

Safe travels!